# Function with For Loop by Row

Tags: python, function, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I am trying to achieve a monte carlo simulation by row (name) in this case, I am able to get the monte carlo simulations but the random normal distribution it is doing is consistent across all names when I am seeking for it to be independent and random by row.  I have exhausted all my ideas and I am seeking help now :)

The result this results in is clearly 'row' specific meaning the rnd.gauss(mean, std) is consistent when I want it to truly be unique and random by row/name.  I have tried adding a for loop utilizing 'name' but it is not working as expected.

```
import random as rnd
import pandas as pd

data = [['lj', 22.72, 37, 9.8], ['nc', 13.24, 30.9, 4.4],['bm', 13.77, 26.3, 9.3], ['jl', 12, 25.9, 7.2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Name', 'Proj', 'Ceil', 'Floor'])

mean = df['Proj'].astype(float)
std = ((df['Ceil'].astype(float) - df['Floor'].astype(float))/2).astype(float)
num_of_sims = 10
name = df['Name']

output = pd.DataFrame([])

def simulation (n):
    simulated_projection = 0
    simulated_projection = rnd.gauss(mean, std)
    return simulated_projection

for i in range(num_of_sims):
    projection = simulation(num_of_sims)
    output = output.append(projection, True)
```

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 19.057055 | 9.671322 | 11.480660 | 9.481726 |
| 1 | 28.160946 | 18.540922 | 17.170591 | 15.740650 |
| 2 | 27.912110 | 18.298490 | 17.015069 | 15.569576 |
| 3 | 35.364650 | 25.559236 | 21.672906 | 20.693197 |
| 4 | 8.840950 | -0.281869 | 5.095593 | 2.458153 |
| 5 | 27.978372 | 18.363047 | 17.056483 | 15.615131 |
| 6 | 47.647661 | 37.526140 | 29.349788 | 29.137767 |
| 7 | 12.740099 | 3.516935 | 7.532562 | 5.138818 |
| 8 | 20.443244 | 11.021837 | 12.347027 | 10.434730 |
| 9 | 33.104873 | 23.357615 | 20.260545 | 19.139600 |

The output is the table above, you can see that the rnd.gauss(mean, std) is creating the desired randomized normal distribution per each column however the randomization per row is consistent.  For example row 3 shows 35 for column 0, column 1 is also a larger value 25, column 2 also a large value 21 etc.  Row 4 show 8 for column 0, column 1 is also small -0.28, column 2 is also small 5 etc.

What I am looking for is the randomization to be independent by row (def simulation) to achieve a more randomized sampling per simulation.

Comment: Can you explain in what way it's not working as expected? Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Certainly I will provide the detail this evening.

Comment: Adding some commentary, hopefully that clears it up.  It's a little tricky to explain.